# Curl - get page with images and css

Tags: c#, php, javascript, jquery

```
<?php
function get_web_page($url)
{
        //echo "curl:url<pre>".$url."</pre><BR>";
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 15,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects

    );

    $ch      = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;

    //change errmsg here to errno
    if ($errmsg)
    {
        echo "CURL:".$errmsg."<BR>";
    }
    return $content;
}
print_r(get_web_page('http://google.com'));
?>
```

Why in this example i havent images and css? How can i get it? Is simply solution for this? I must add http://google.com before all links, but how?

Comment: You do realize that images and css don't automatically come as part of a webpage?  A browser (for example) has to follow all the links individually and request each resource one-by-one (often in parallel) to download the linked content from their individual url's.  An easy way to understand this is to access your test page while running a proxy like Fiddler in the background, and watch what requests pass over the network.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably interested in a library such as this: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/

libcurl cannot natively act as a webcrawler, because it does not analyze page contents. That's a job you have to do yourself.